# Should action listeners be in the class they apply to?

Tags: java, class, static, actionlistener

I'm programming a web browser with multiple classes. One class is "navbar" which holds most of the buttons such as search, back, forward, etc. 
The navbar class has action listeners which, when the search button is pressed, become active, and lead to the production of a URL, which needs to be passed to the JEditorPane, but the editor pane is in a different class, "editor".

It does not make sense for an editor to be instantiated inside navbar, so how can i pass the variable from the navbar class to the editor class?

**Is it okay to use statics in this situation?**

Comment: Could you give some sample of what you're trying to do? You say "use statics" but don't say how you're thinking of using them. Typically the listeners of a control are in the class that they apply to, but the action they take when something happens could be to call a method of a different class.

Comment: try {
       String hp;
       hp = browser.homePage;
       editor.jep.setPage(hp);
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

Comment: ^ this is some sample code inside the navBar. The try statement is setting the editor classes JEditorPane (jep), but is only able to do some because i have made the jep static

Comment: It might be nicer to use `Action`s extending `AbstractAction` instead of `ActionListeners`. Swing passes Actions around (menu+toolbar), for instance Cut-Copy-Paste actions for editing. Also undo/redo actions can be done as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply give the nav bar a reference to the editor? This could be done in the constructor, if the editor is instantiated first, or via getter/setter pair (actually, only the setter is really needed...). If the nav bar has such a reference, it can call the appropriate methods from within the listener implementation.

```
class Editor { ... }
class NavBar implements ActionListener
{
    public NavBar(Editor editor)
    {
        myEditor = editor;
    }
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        // call methods of myEditor
    }

    private Editor myEditor;
}

Editor theEditor = new Editor();
NavBar theNavBar = new NavBar(theEditor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of intermediate interface between these, typically a service like layer. Which is basically what the observer pattern is as well. The editor could list events the navbar produces, but that also means later on you could also catch these events in other components